# Transistor Not Entering in Cutoff region

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, dc, logic-gates

I have constructed these circuits, utilizing either DTL or TTL logic, and I'm aiming to place transistors T1, T2, and T3 into the cutoff region. However, I'm currently unable to achieve this. Could you please advise me on which parameter I should modify to ensure these transistors enter the cutoff region?
[image]

[Circuit simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEBmAHAJmgdgGzoRmACzICcpkORIOESJICApgLRhgBQA7iC%20utVSRe-amHSooHAE4iBIIXOpscUcPA4BzXuMmlVbCeCLVhkGTqNVLklWrAaASkp0HRvZOjXCiwpGahoBA4AGREEVUUWZEhBAOEAMwBDABsAZyZGQPRQ8NVdD1jwI2EIZPTM-2gcnkNJaxZFa3MAWV4m5SJ60xBMYM8QAB0AsFh4cYm4MFYwVRGg717wZZGOABdXYSiCxVKRaBxaSCwsBCJ0ZCIcU4jAw%20QwAn0cUiwSWYgHYWGOABMXbakLyKLy-JjJACuKTWfx0QIUwhUW2EoPBSShMP%20fHkUXwkRRIDBkOhsOxYiMfFuBVRxJhtQKdjJrik2kapQpimIPXMPFmAWaUn%201i5KC8Ipp6JJQuo%20lFIFlEoxuQGIrsIr25QyWXMYQGsrssoCmsqUmcAoas0Wvm13iCFmssoFpQ0PAdqmFJikrpl%20SMhvWxT0%20Vw8rmyxYRGgJlQCFeYCEqGI4iwgQQcC6r3IqCICCw5GQ6mERMlMNkYBD7DFFZDzrgFnL%20PANfsLvAOBGzfMGwb4HEvSwYr7e2i0BiJzT5cgMTApFzplg%20AIDyXBEouapcEJaKVPHQA8D-arc24h6bwfPXrPV57M685m0N-hPfQkEkZgse68Cv3ltrPNPlqft4J49ii%207vru%206yp4wj%20m0MGhigCBfmGfQcG0WDIPkfa4JIlZqGhrqoHhOFYb2d4nrGXjRF4ODER4FHaFRvSvow8LuBBbFivCzEvm%20J50XhPFPvC-6CcY1DibeUgbMxBRSSU4bINAqA4LGRCzpADhXGmyBVFpGB6cQabEdmhyFlutKUSGNFcQxUiyMxspyWGXzmI5T5GHJongGmdayZ6%20FyUO4aRggZBUJc5ZfFgGCBOcszESQhADgZFnFjuIBdKUfbZW276yHl%20FFWGRBYHWzh5bZVVdFafiLDAwRhNG5FZZu%20FGqkWr%20LkLV8m1pTtvYIDGtqsJFbltX4YqUpZZyQ19UNM10owNkDFVAxdjQ1q1eJtV7DA-CzmQ8bXPolx7m%20BziGVOaoGgCDiJQYqbhls3idYUl9st9r0bZ4mbeAMQnhtXglZeLl2bZ-5Oe61r%20t6PjdLBx6QUeoqlDWAn0dJmH5KJFhsgeRMCi%20dayAhPYIYaLHkyAePgPCDMdbT5j-BNXiPYOXg-f8XOtWcYjfZZJYcAAHjoAyqToRSoKQWW9NQAAqnAS-GBakJI6DsOoEDUPISs5BLsYFk9NDa8UBb68ryAcAA9jQ3RqL45DamMDz4ARjsoPbNDywKLvy-pU7iEgEC0fLtsO%20V23O5ArsOIEcAe0gPP08IttAA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the steering diodes there will be 1 diode drop (~0.6V) so the transistor base is never going to be below that and it will not fully cut off.

You could add a resistor from the base to ground to pull it a bit lower, but that brings additional current draw.

Back when they used this sort of logic one thing they would do is use Germanium diodes which have a voltage drop of around 0.3V, so the base would be pulled closer to ground. Another way of doing it was to use a negative voltage, which is why you see older logic with both positive and negative supplies. Here is a circuit using a resistor from the base to a negative voltage:
[image: By Inductiveload - Own work, Public Domain, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=5741538]

Answer (score 3):

Typical old-timey DTL 3-input NAND gate made with discrete components :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuLOHq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This is DTL logic. You have to ground any input to turn off the input transistor.